# Why does java support different types of JVMs such as CVM, KVM?

Tags: java, jvm, kvm, jvm-languages

We know that JAVA has several types of vitual machine supported. Why it's needed where Java could run based on one single/standard JVM?
Why does java support different types of JVMs such as CVM, KVM?

Comment: JVM implementations are written according to a JVM spec. Its left to the people writing JVMs to ensure that everything works fine

Comment: Because they are reference implementation as Vlnod mentioned they are following a spec

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Why wouldn't different implementations be implemented different ways?

Comment: The answer is: It doesn't. It is not Java that supports different JVMs. It's the different JVMs that support Java.

Answer (score 1):

When java was invented theire was a specification generated, which describes how to excecute the ByteCode produced by the Java compiler.

The Reason for that was, that java initially was designed for set-up boxes and other small devices and not for servers or desktop computers.

Because these devices all had different Hardware and Operating Systems (If they had one) multiple implementions of the JVM where needed for different  Hardware.

For today, this means that anybody can implement a JVM and its not under controll of the Company behind java. As a added benefit Java runs everywhere, from a smart card over a secure element in a Mobile phone, to some network devices and finally on a personal computer or a server.